# assign gradient of colours based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, colors

I have a df which looks like this

df

```
ID     Pass  R2   fix
mutaA.  1.   0.9.  2
mutaA.  2.   0.9.  2
mutaA.  3.   0.9.  2
mutaA.  4.   0.9.  2
mutaB.  1.   0.3.  6
mutaB.  2.   0.3.  6
mutaB.  3.   0.3.  6
mutaB.  4.   0.3.  6
mutaC.  1.   0.9.  1
mutaC.  3.   0.9.  1
mutaC.  4.   0.9.  1
mutaD.  1.   0.3.  3
mutaD.  2.   0.3.  3
mutaD.  3.   0.3.  3
mutaD.  4.   0.3.  3
```

I would like to assign:

- colour green to all the rows where `fix >= 6`
- a gradient of blue to the rows where the R2 is >= 0.9. The gradient goes from light blue at low Pass value (1) to dark blue at high Pass value (5). Please, note that some Pass values in certain groups are skipped such as mutaC
- Anything else that does not satisfies those conditions it is in white.

Output

```
ID     Pass  R2   fix. col
mutaA.  1.   0.9.  2.  #BFBFFF
mutaA.  2.   0.9.  2.  #7879FF
mutaA.  3.   0.9.  2.  #4949FF
mutaA.  4.   0.9.  2.  #1F1FFF
mutaA.  5.   0.9.  6.  #0000FF
mutaB.  1.   0.3.  6   #006400
mutaB.  2.   0.3.  6   #006400
mutaB.  3.   0.3.  6   #006400
mutaB.  4.   0.3.  6   #006400
mutaB.  5.   0.3.  6   #006400
mutaC.  1.   0.9.  1   #BFBFFF
mutaC.  3.   0.9.  1.  #4949FF
mutaC.  4.   0.9.  1.  #1F1FFF
mutaD.  1.   0.3.  3.  #FFFFFF
mutaD.  2.   0.3.  3.  #FFFFFF
mutaD.  3.   0.3.  3.  #FFFFFF
mutaD.  4.   0.3.  3.  #FFFFFF


    structure(list(tag = c("HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_C _ Synonymous _ 1445", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1153", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1581", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1581", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1599", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1599", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1686", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1686", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1686", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1686", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1773", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1997", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1997", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1997", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 1997", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 2060", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 2060", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 2216", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 2219", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 2219", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 2456", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 2664", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3461", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3647", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3647", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3647", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3780", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3780", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3852", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3852", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 3944", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 424", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 4241", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 4406", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 4406", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 4439", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 4439", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 4439", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 4514", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Nonsynonymous _ 4565", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Synonymous _ 2608", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Synonymous _ 3070", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Synonymous _ 3070", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Synonymous _ 3070", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Synonymous _ 3070", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Synonymous _ 3517", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_G _ Synonymous _ 659", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 2154", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3570", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3570", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 3756", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 4487", 
"HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 759", "HIV1gp1 _ A_to_T _ Nonsynonymous _ 825", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1444", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 1557", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 3456", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 3510", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 397", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 397", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 397", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 397", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 397", "HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 397", 
"HIV1gp1 _ C_to_A _ Nonsynonymous _ 397"), freq = c(33.3333, 
99.5393, 99.6554, 99.5531, 99.1764, 99.7657, 99.529, 99.5011, 
99.4036, 99.8749, 99.3893, 5.9906, 25.7075, 28.3844, 34.0173, 
23.7103, 5.7059, 68.6055, 99.8318, 99.3371, 10.8472, 8.9959, 
41.6912, 50.7579, 78.6495, 37.3339, 17.1455, 7.052, 69.6965, 
70.0769, 19.6264, 14.4621, 25.3148, 76.3171, 97.0255, 99.1103, 
32.307, 14.0812, 6.3022, 7.0757, 23.5069, 100, 66.6667, 40, 100, 
50, 90.9091, 90, 100, 80, 9.5432, 12.535, 8.7842, 5.6453, 31.6525, 
33.4385, 5.9385, 6.8705, 20.3082, 37.3105, 51.0737, 40.368, 16.6985, 
6.8304, 8.0783, 7.4664, 12.8373, 10.0867, 19.3267, 44.327, 93.2471, 
99.5702, 99.6351, 99.7447, 99.0479, 99.3232, 99.4721, 99.3463, 
5.0634, 5.3793, 5.2675, 9.9816, 26.8402, 29.6989, 35.6655, 36.4335, 
99.6447, 99.6378, 99.597, 99.2001, 99.5647, 8.2511, 17.1438, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), Pass1 = c(60L, 30L, 60L, 
90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 270L, 210L, 240L, 
270L, 300L, 210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 210L, 210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 
90L, 120L, 180L, 270L, 300L, 240L, 300L, 240L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 
150L, 180L, 60L, 90L, 300L, 30L, 60L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 210L, 
240L, 270L, 300L, 300L, 270L, 300L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 180L, 180L, 
300L, 210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 300L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 150L, 30L, 
60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 270L, 30L, 
60L, 120L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 210L, 240L, 270L, 300L, 
60L, 30L, 120L, 150L, 180L, 210L, 240L, 270L, 300L), squared = c(0, 
-0.1246984, -0.1246984, -0.1246984, -0.1246984, -0.1246984, -0.1246984, 
-0.1246984, -0.1246984, -0.1246984, -0.1246984, 0, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, 0.7435069, 0.7435069, 0.7435069, 0.7435069, 0, 0.9418341, 
0.9418341, 0.9418341, 0.9418341, NaN, NaN, 0, NaN, NaN, 0, 0, 
0, 0.635947, 0.635947, 0.635947, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, -0.1031436, 
-0.1031436, -0.1031436, -0.1031436, -0.1031436, -0.1031436, -0.1031436, 
-0.1031436, -0.1031436, 0, NaN, NaN, 0.595967, 0.595967, 0.595967, 
0, 0, 0, 0.1365324, 0.1365324, 0.1365324, 0.1365324, 0, 0, 0, 
NaN, NaN, 0.460988, 0.460988, 0.460988, 0.460988, 0.460988, 0.460988, 
0.460988, 0.460988, 0.460988, 0.460988, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.7517348, 
0.7517348, 0.7517348, 0.7517348, 0.7517348, 0.7517348, 0.7517348, 
0.7517348, 0.7517348, 0, 0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
), n = c(0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
0L, 0L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L)), row.names = c(89L, 1L, 
90L, 231L, 385L, 621L, 840L, 1082L, 1341L, 1609L, 1895L, 1610L, 
1083L, 1342L, 1611L, 1896L, 1084L, 1343L, 1612L, 1897L, 1085L, 
1086L, 1344L, 1613L, 1898L, 232L, 386L, 841L, 1614L, 1899L, 1345L, 
1900L, 1346L, 1347L, 1615L, 1901L, 622L, 842L, 91L, 233L, 1902L, 
2L, 92L, 387L, 623L, 843L, 1087L, 1348L, 1616L, 1903L, 1904L, 
1617L, 1905L, 93L, 234L, 388L, 844L, 845L, 1906L, 1088L, 1349L, 
1618L, 1907L, 1908L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 624L, 3L, 94L, 235L, 392L, 
625L, 846L, 1089L, 1350L, 1619L, 1909L, 1620L, 4L, 95L, 393L, 
96L, 236L, 394L, 626L, 847L, 1090L, 1351L, 1621L, 1910L, 97L, 
5L, 395L, 627L, 848L, 1091L, 1352L, 1622L, 1911L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a vector of the blue gradient colors, then assign your colors based on your conditions using e.g. `dplyr::case_when`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

pal_blues <- c("#BFBFFF", "#7879FF", "#4949FF", "#1F1FFF", "#0000FF")

dat |>
  mutate(
    color = case_when(
      R2 >= .9 ~ pal_blues[Pass],
      fix >= 6 ~ "#006400",
      .default = "white"
    )
  )
#>        ID Pass   R2 fix   color
#> 1  mutaA.    1 0.9.   2 #BFBFFF
#> 2  mutaA.    2 0.9.   2 #7879FF
#> 3  mutaA.    3 0.9.   2 #4949FF
#> 4  mutaA.    4 0.9.   2 #1F1FFF
#> 5  mutaA.    5 0.9.   6 #0000FF
#> 6  mutaB.    1 0.3.   6 #006400
#> 7  mutaB.    2 0.3.   6 #006400
#> 8  mutaB.    3 0.3.   6 #006400
#> 9  mutaB.    4 0.3.   6 #006400
#> 10 mutaB.    5 0.3.   6 #006400
#> 11 mutaC.    1 0.9.   1 #BFBFFF
#> 12 mutaC.    3 0.9.   1 #4949FF
#> 13 mutaC.    4 0.9.   1 #1F1FFF
#> 14 mutaD.    1 0.3.   3   white
#> 15 mutaD.    2 0.3.   3   white
#> 16 mutaD.    3 0.3.   3   white
#> 17 mutaD.    4 0.3.   3   white
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- structure(list(
  ID = c(
    "mutaA.", "mutaA.", "mutaA.", "mutaA.",
    "mutaA.", "mutaB.", "mutaB.", "mutaB.", "mutaB.", "mutaB.", "mutaC.",
    "mutaC.", "mutaC.", "mutaD.", "mutaD.", "mutaD.", "mutaD."
  ),
  Pass = c(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3,
    4
  ), R2 = c(
    "0.9.", "0.9.", "0.9.", "0.9.", "0.9.", "0.3.",
    "0.3.", "0.3.", "0.3.", "0.3.", "0.9.", "0.9.", "0.9.", "0.3.",
    "0.3.", "0.3.", "0.3."
  ), fix = c(
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -17L
))
```

Comment: it is coloring the white and green correctly but all the rows where the gradient is supposed to be have NA values

Comment: Hm. The issue is most likely with the data type of the `Pass` column ,e.g. when it is a character you get NAs. That's one of the reasons why it is best to share your data via `dput()`.  Try with `pal_blues[as.integer(Pass)]`

Comment: yes, that is what I thought, I changed it to integer but still the same

Comment: my fix column is integer, my Pass is integer and my R2 is numeric

Comment: Could you share your data via `dput()`, i.e. run `dput(df[1:15,])` and copy the output into your post?

Comment: I added sample of my data

Comment: sorry I edited to be better, the columns are these ID=tag Pass=Pass1 R2=squared fix=n

Comment: maybe the issue is with the R2 column, it is numeric in my case

Comment: Nop. The issue is simply that in your real data the values in your `Pass` or `Pass1` column are different from 1 to 6, they range from 30 to 300 in steps of 30. Accounting for that requires a different approach, e.g. pal_blues[as.integer(factor(Pass))] should do the job. But if there are more than 5 different values you have to extend the color palette too.

Comment: you are right, it worked

Answer (score 2):

Similar to stefan's answer, but using the built-in function `colorRampPalette()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(col = case_when(
    fix >= 6 ~ "#006400",
    R2 >= 0.9 ~ colorRampPalette(c("lightblue", "darkblue"))(5)[Pass],
    TRUE ~ "#FFFFFF"),
    .by = ID) -> df

# to visualise it:
DT::datatable(df) |> DT::formatStyle(names(df), backgroundColor = DT::styleRow(1:nrow(df), df$col))
```

Output:
[image: table with color]

Comment: it is coloring the white and green correctly but all the rows where the gradient is supposed to be have NA values

Comment: uhhh are you using the same input as me? because I saw you had the same response to stefan's answer

Comment: Also are you using the same code to visualise it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution. The colors are not the colors posted in the question since I am using base function `colorRampPalette` to create the colors values.

```r
# default values
df$col <- "#FFFFFF"  # bright white

# assign one green color only
df$col[df$fix >= 6L] <- colorRampPalette("green")(1L)

# create blues gradient, as many blues as different Pass values
clr_ramp_blue <- colorRampPalette(c("lightblue", "darkblue"))
blues <- unique(df$Pass) |> length() |> clr_ramp_blue()
# now assign the blues gradient
i_fix <- df$fix < 6L
i_r2 <- df$R2 >= 0.9
df$col[i_fix & i_r2] <- blues[df$Pass][i_fix & i_r2]

# see the result
df
#>        ID Pass  R2 fix     col
#> 1  mutaA.    1 0.9   2 #ADD8E6
#> 2  mutaA.    2 0.9   2 #7390C7
#> 3  mutaA.    3 0.9   2 #3948A9
#> 4  mutaA.    4 0.9   2 #00008B
#> 5  mutaB.    1 0.3   6 #00FF00
#> 6  mutaB.    2 0.3   6 #00FF00
#> 7  mutaB.    3 0.3   6 #00FF00
#> 8  mutaB.    4 0.3   6 #00FF00
#> 9  mutaC.    1 0.9   1 #ADD8E6
#> 10 mutaC.    3 0.9   1 #3948A9
#> 11 mutaC.    4 0.9   1 #00008B
#> 12 mutaD.    1 0.3   3 #FFFFFF
#> 13 mutaD.    2 0.3   3 #FFFFFF
#> 14 mutaD.    3 0.3   3 #FFFFFF
#> 15 mutaD.    4 0.3   3 #FFFFFF
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Plot the result with `ggplot2`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

clrs <- setNames(df$col, df$col)
ggplot(df, aes(Pass, fix, color = col |> factor(), group = ID)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, shape = 19, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = clrs) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

The posted `R2` values have two dots and are read in as character. The code below coerces them to numeric.

```r
df <- read.table(text = "
ID     Pass  R2   fix
mutaA.  1.   0.9.  2
mutaA.  2.   0.9.  2
mutaA.  3.   0.9.  2
mutaA.  4.   0.9.  2
mutaB.  1.   0.3.  6
mutaB.  2.   0.3.  6
mutaB.  3.   0.3.  6
mutaB.  4.   0.3.  6
mutaC.  1.   0.9.  1
mutaC.  3.   0.9.  1
mutaC.  4.   0.9.  1
mutaD.  1.   0.3.  3
mutaD.  2.   0.3.  3
mutaD.  3.   0.3.  3
mutaD.  4.   0.3.  3"
, header = TRUE)
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    15 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ ID  : chr  "mutaA." "mutaA." "mutaA." "mutaA." ...
#>  $ Pass: num  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 ...
#>  $ R2  : chr  "0.9." "0.9." "0.9." "0.9." ...
#>  $ fix : int  2 2 2 2 6 6 6 6 1 1 ...
df$R2 <- sub("\\.$", "", df$R2) |> as.numeric()
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    15 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ ID  : chr  "mutaA." "mutaA." "mutaA." "mutaA." ...
#>  $ Pass: num  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 3 ...
#>  $ R2  : num  0.9 0.9 0.9 0.9 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.9 0.9 ...
#>  $ fix : int  2 2 2 2 6 6 6 6 1 1 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Error in data1$col[i_fix & i_r2] <- blues[data1$Pass1][i_fix & i_r2] : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini Have you coerced `R2` to numeric, like I do? Check each of the `i_*` indices to see what are their values.

Comment: yes, but it was found out that the Pass column has to be treated as factor

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini Can't you leave it as integer and treat it as factor only when needed?